# Detect the current top cell in a UITableView after scrolling

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad, uitableview

a simple question but I don't seem to have the right terminology to search Stackoverflow by it.

I have a UITableView with no sections, the user can scroll up and down a long list of data (rows) presented inside this tableview.

**Question:** how can I detect the most top cell row number after the user scrolled.
(for example, if the user is scrolling 30 cells down, the top cell after the scroll is = 30)

Answer (score 77, accepted):

You could try using `UITableView`'s `-indexPathsForVisibleRows` or `-indexPathForRowAtPoint`.

For example, let's say that you want to print the indexPath of the topmost visible cell, when you stop dragging your table. You could do something like this:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate{
    NSIndexPath *firstVisibleIndexPath = [[self.tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows] objectAtIndex:0];
    NSLog(@"first visible cell's section: %i, row: %i", firstVisibleIndexPath.section, firstVisibleIndexPath.row);
}
```

For Swift 3.0

```
let topVisibleIndexPath:IndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows![0]
```

Comment: I would sort the array as there's nothing (as far as I can see) in the documentation that says the index paths are sorted in ascending order.

Comment: It's a different question, but check `tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath`

Comment: Beware, `[self.tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows]` could be empty when the user scrolls a table view with bouncing enabled like a chick on speed. So be sure to check whether the method returned at least 1 index path.

Comment: "indexPathsForVisibleRows" returns invisible rows as well. Any better approach?

Answer (score 32):

You get the index paths for the visible rows

```
NSArray* indexPaths = [tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows];
```

Then sort using `compare:`

```
NSArray* sortedIndexPaths = [indexPaths sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
```

Then get the first element's row

```
NSInteger row = [(NSIndexPath*)[sortedIndexPaths objectAtIndex:0] row];
```

Comment: This solution works on `UICollectionView`s along with `UITableView`s

Answer (score 8):

This is the Swift 3+ code:

```
override func scrollViewDidEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, willDecelerate decelerate: Bool) {
    let firstVisibleIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows?[0]
    print("First visible cell section=\(firstVisibleIndexPath?.section), and row=\(firstVisibleIndexPath?.row)")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**In Swift 4:**

```swift
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let firstVisibleIndexPath = self.tableview.indexPathsForVisibleRows?[0]
    print("top visible cell section  is \([firstVisibleIndexPath!.section])")
}
```