# UITableViewCells with avplayer

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, avplayer

I am populating a tableview with data from web and I have 3 kind of cells one with image, a label and buttons, one with webview, label and buttons, and the last one with avplayer, label and buttons.

I implemented infinite scroll on that tableview. So I have many cells. What I am trying to do is play videos in my video cells with loop and play those videos like Vine app.

I mean I want videos to play when that video cell is top visible cell. Otherwise it will be stopped. How can I achieve that goal? Could you please point me out to right way?

Comment: Here you go: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8259511/2700842

Comment: Thank you Nick that was a really good start. Is it possible to detect how much of cell's ContentView is visible at the end of dragging ?

Comment: I don't think that's possible, but it is possible for you to set which cell is visible at the end of dragging.