# UITableView & Sections - to detect if a section header is stays on top

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I need this because I need to change the background color of a section. For example, if section at the top then blue green otherwise.

I have tried many things but I am with my ideas at the end.

Comment: What do you mean "snapped to top"?

Comment: i mean when a section stay´s on top.

Comment: a whole section, or some header? please be much more specific. and it would be helpful to see at least one approach of those you are mentioning.

Comment: Only the header not the whole section.

Comment: Where are the codes you tried?

Comment: the codes from the answers. but they work not correctly for my problem. the header color is set only in one direction but not back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayHeaderView:(UIView *)view forSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Background color
    view.backgroundColor = section == 0 ? [UIColor blueColor] : [UIColor greenColor];

    // Another way to set the background color
    // Note: does not preserve gradient effect of original header
    // UITableViewHeaderFooterView *header = (UITableViewHeaderFooterView *)view;
    // header.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
}
```

Considering top means 1st section.

**Edit**

If you want to change color according to scrolling and identifying which section is on top and which is not then you have to implement UIScrollViewDelegate so that you can handle scrolling delegates. You can try something like this

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate{
    NSIndexPath *firstVisibleIndexPath = [[self.tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows] objectAtIndex:0];
    NSLog(@"first visible cell's section: %i, row: %i", firstVisibleIndexPath.section, firstVisibleIndexPath.row);
}
```

References: [UIScrollViewDelegate implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8642699/uitableview-scroll-event) and [Detecting top cell in TableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8259475/detect-the-current-top-cell-in-a-uitableview-after-scrolling)

Comment: Not really, i mean a section is on top. I know my question is not clear enough. But i will try you solution. It sounds very good. 
One think: 'view.backgroundColor' is deprecated use 'contentView.backgroundColor' say´s Xcode.

Comment: This is incorrect. Section 0 may or may not be displayed depending on content length and number of sections.

Comment: Your solution is clean :) I only gave the path to follow but you answered it precisely (Y)

Comment: It´s not really correct working but i will try fix it.

Comment: That is the spirit my friend :)

Comment: After your edit, I removed my downvote. The problem with `scrollViewDidEndDragging` is it will only work after a user lifts his finger.

Comment: - (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView can help in that case, I hope so.

Comment: That would be too slow, as after every scroll point, you will query the table view for displayed cells' index paths. `willDisplayHeaderView` is the correct spot.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayHeaderView:(UIView *)view forSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSArray* visibleCellIndexPaths = [tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows];

    //Set all header views to have a blue background color.
    [view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];

    if(visibleCellIndexPaths.count > 0)
    {
        //Set the topmost visible section header view to have green background color.
        [[tableView headerViewForSection:[visibleCellIndexPaths[0] section]] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just check if the frame of the section header you're looking for has moved to the top.

Answer (score 0):

Swift version of @faisal Ali answer

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int) {
    view.backgroundColor = section == 0 ? UIColor.white : UIColor.clear
}
```